# how to position the dynamically sized label always the center in a view of specific width?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had an application in which i had a button which needs to be located at the end of a dynamic label as like appending it ,I had tried this but its showing some times ok (correct position)and some times not ok(not at the right position)manner.I am doing like this.also i need to position the label always the center `

```
label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(105,9,160, 30)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18]];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.numberOfLines = 1;
    label.text=myString;
    [[self.view viewWithTag:300] addSubview:label];
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
     CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size = expectedLabelSize;
    if(newFrame.size.width>160.0)
      newFrame.size.width=150.0; 
      label.frame = newFrame;
    [label setCenter:CGPointMake(300/2,40/2)];
     button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(newFrame.origin.x+newFrame.size.width,13,20,20)];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`can anybody point me in where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Set this frame to button ..

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(newFrame.origin.x+newFrame.size.width,13,20,20)];
```

Your y coordinate is fixed so you need to change it dynamically

Comment: what u mean by this.i am adding the button after the label like in dropdown box not bellow the label..

Comment: thats the problem. First try to remove it and run it again you will see your result.

Comment: but u r answer is about y cordinate and i want x cordinate

Comment: i've changed it....and change these line up and down..  [label setCenter:CGPointMake(300/2,40/2)]; label.frame = newFrame;